# changing python version in Spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am trying to configure Spyder to work with python version 3.6.7.
I created a new environment with version 3.6.7 and opened Spyder through it. However, it keeps showing python 3.6.6.
Any ideas?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) You need to activate your environment before launching Spyder, else you're launching the Spyder version present in your PATH.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I activated it and launched spyder from there ( spyder /n). Yet, it says python 3.6.6 in the spyder IDE

Comment: Then please run `spyder --reset` in a terminal and try again.